# Embedding an existing UIViewController into a new UINavigationController in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode7

[EDIT after duplicate detected]
Here's my context :

- I have a series of UIViewController linked by segues
- I create a new class 'NavigationControllerDelegate' which extends NSObject and UINavigationControllerDelegate (in order to manage transition animation)
- In Interface Builder, I inserted a new UINavigationController
- I link it with the class 'NavigationControllerDelegate'
- In IB, I inserted an object in the UINavigationController and declared it as the delegate

I need now to link this navigation controller to the existing view controller.

In Interface Builder (Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)) , I want to know how to include an existing UIViewController into a brand new UINavigationController ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it following these steps:

Select your `viewcontroller` from `editor` select `embed in` then select `navigation controller` from option

And your view controller will get new navigation controller with relationship segue.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: This is different way from user's answer. It's just for sharing knowledge man! Because user have already given answer so, he/she will not accept this answer. It is only for just informing that there is another way to do this also.! @AshishKakkad

Comment: I tried your solution, but my context is a bit different. See my updated question...Your solution insert a new NavigationController. I followed another way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer :

1. Insert a new UINavigationController in the storyboard. It will be the Storyboard Entry Point
2. Ctrl+Click on the NavigationController and drag a link to the ViewController. A contextual menu should appear as below

[image]

3. Choose **Relationship Segue > root view controller**
4. A new segue should link the navigation controller and the view controller
5. A navigation bar should appear on top of the view controller

[image]

6. A new navigation bar is inserted
7. In the navigator view, on the left, you have a new relationship "root view controller" to "View Controller"

[image]
[image]

Comment: you already have an answer :) then why you put this question for wasting so space :| because i see the time of question and time or answer both are same

Answer (score 1):

Just two steps:

1) Select view controller which you want to embed in UINavigationController

[image]

2) Go to Editor > Embed In > UINavigation Controller

[image]

You are done...

[image]